# ajax zend params

Tags: jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I am dealing with receiving params in an action, from an ajax call.

Once in a view, i m getting some values (geolocation)
then i make an ajax call ($.get()) like

```
controller/action/lat/xxx/long/xxx
```

to query a db.

In the action i called, i try to get the params via

```
$lat = $this->_request->getParam("lat");
$long = $this->_request->getParam("long");
```

BUT,

I m gettinig the params of the url i am in (browser url, not of the ajax url)

any light?
THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) instead of `$.get()` If you do not want parameters to be send through url .

```
public function indexAction()
{
  $ret = array();
  $lat = $this->_getParam('lat');
  $long = $this->_getParam('long');
   //save it in your database
   $ret['msg'] = 'Record saved';
  $this->_helper->json($ret); 


}
```

Comment: thanks! but regardless of get or post, i am not finding how to actually "read" the params sent, once in the action..

Comment: I am going to close it. There where many other things (bad url, not checking in the action if it was an ajax request) that where putting me in the situation of not getting the params!.. thank you!